# Heisenberg principle vs inertial invariance

Tags: quantum-mechanics, special-relativity, inertial-frames, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle

Heisenberg's principle

$$\Delta p \, \Delta x > \hbar,$$

so

$$\Delta x> \hbar/\Delta p.$$

If an object is in an inertial system it will have zero velocity,
therefore: $p=mass * velocity =0$ and $\Delta p=0$. What would $\Delta x$ be then?

In other words: if he object is not accelerated and therefore in his own inertial system his velocity is 0, then $\Delta p$ should be 0 as well. Give that, $\Delta x$ would be an infinite value; That would even apply to any object regardless of it's mass; How can that be physically possible?

Comment: “if an object is in an inertial system it will have zero velocity” this isn’t true so perhaps you could edit the question to explain your reasoning

Comment: Welcome to Physics.SE! Thanks for posting. We recommend you format mathematical expressions using MathJax/LaTeX.

Answer (score 1):

In Quantum mechanics, Eigenstate with certain momentum has the form $\psi (x,t)= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi \hbar}}e^{\frac{i}{\hbar}(p_x x -E t)}$, which is spreaded uniformly to infinite space. Therefore, if you establish a state with momentum without any momentum uncertainty, the $\Delta x$ will be infinite.